# php page not displaying arabic text

Tags: php, character-encoding, internationalization

I have a PHP page where I am trying to display Arabic text but its showing.

In MySQL database I'm storing arabic text successfully.

I'm using the following code to connect to the database :

```
function connect(){
$this->dbLink = mysql_connect($this->dbHost,$this->dbUser,$this->dbPass);   
if(!$this->dbLink) die("Could not connect to database. " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($this->dbName);
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $this->dbLink); 
}
```

And using the following header in the PHP page :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

But still no success.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: both headers together ? joking?

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` ?

Comment: your browser should show you the character set and let you change it.

Comment: @air Is that a question?

Comment: @yoda the problem is Arabic text didn't display it only echo ??????

Comment: @air do you have a url we can look at?

Comment: @yoda its in localhost, see the page is working fine like if i put Arabic text in page, it display properly but only text coming from database display ?????

Comment: as i said before i am using this statement in connection mysql_set_charset("utf8", $this->dbLink);

Comment: You are mixing up PHP and HTML. It's the **HTML** page, not displaying Arabic text and it's not "header in the PHP page" but META-information to the HTML-site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this meta code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And please check mysql column's character type..

Look to [this](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=100099)

Comment: i have same meata and column's character type is utf and collection is utf_general_ci and as i said, Arabic is saving properly in database.

Comment: shortly you hava problem ,when you select data? true?

Answer (score 3):

check the file encoding, it should be UTF-8, and you can try to run the following query before querying the text:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Addtional to the headers set in the meta section, check your default_charset setting in the php.ini. default_charset should be empty if you set content type header by your own or correspond with your content-type meta information.

Answer (score 1):

You set a META-tag that tells the browser to use ISO-8859-1 (`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />`), which is for latin-based scripts, but surely not Arabic.

Also make sure you have UTF-8 at all places:

- the DB-column
- the DB-connection (you already have it)
- the website (via HTTP-header OR META-tag, you don't need both, and you don't need a second META-tag, as stated above…)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the connection to use UTF-8 (with mysql_set_charset)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this two lines to your php script after the Mysql connection

`mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1256");
mysql_query("set character set cp1256");`